# Add strikethrought to the specific rows of listView populated from Database in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a `ListView` where i populate it with data from `Database`. When i populate i am checking for those rows that have `tn_selected = 1`. Those who have returned 1 will be displayed with a `strike-through line` on the text of those rows while the others will show only the text without strike-through. I red a lot of questions in stack-overflow but couldn't achieve that. Any help is appreciated.

Database table looks like this:

```
tn_id | tn_item | tn_selected
-----------------------------
  1   | item1   |     0
-----------------------------
  2   | item2   |     0
-----------------------------
  3   | item3   |     1
-----------------------------
```

Method to get data from DB:

```
public Cursor getAllItems(Context context){
    String sql = "SELECT " + COLUMN_TN_ID + " as _id, " + COLUMN_TN_ITEM + "," + COLUMN_TN_SELECTED + " FROM " + TN_TABLE_NAME; 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

*Where:
  **COLUMN_TN_ID** is the* 'tn_id' *field
  **COLUMN_TN_ITEM** is the* 'tn_item' *field
in the DB*

Here is the method that sets data to the SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
private void populateListView() {
    // Set adapter for ListView
    ListView lvTest = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems); 

    Cursor cursor = DBhelper.getAllItems(this);

    // Manage cursor activity(when to close it if you don't know
    // when)[DEBRECATED - Use Cursor Loader instead]
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Setup Mapping from cursor to view fields
    String[] fromFieldNames = { DBhelper.COLUMN_TN_ITEM};
    int[] toViewIDs = { R.id.tvTouristItem };
    // Create adapter to add DB data into elements of UI
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context
            R.layout.tn_listview_row, // Row Layout template
            cursor, // Cursor
            fromFieldNames, // DB Column names
            toViewIDs, // View IDs to put information
            0 // Flag
    );
    //Bind view to simpleCursorAdapter
    cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

            String tnItem = cursor.getString(TN_ITEM_COLUMN);
            int itemIsSelected = cursor.getInt(TN_SELECTED_COLUMN);

            ((TextView) view).setText(tnItem);

            if(itemIsSelected == 1){
                int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.tn_list_selected_row_background);
                view.setBackgroundColor(color);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
    lvTest.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: use a ViewBinder (set by setViewBinder)

Comment: @pskink thnx for helping. When i setViewBinder it means that i dont have to setAdapter(lvTest.setAdapter(cursorAdapter) also, is it right? But instead set ViewBinder directly and do the operations there (cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new Binder....))?

Comment: no, you have to use both: setAdapter and setviewBinder

Comment: @pskink Thanx dude for helping. I solved it and wrote the answer below  so the others can see the solution. However one weird thing is happening into listView. When they are loaded, they are loaded correctly(those who have a 'tn_selected = 1' are strikedthrough), but when i scroll the list-view back and forward, random rows text is being strikedthrough too. Im searching for this issue on the net but if you had this issue before i would appreciate your further help

Comment: you have to clear the flag in "else" branch of your "if"

Comment: it has nothing to do with Android,  it's just bit setting/clearing, just google on how to do that in java

Comment: @pskink ok dude thnx. It did the work and i updated the code below too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] 
Problem is solved. Here is the solution to bind a strikethrough line. Just update the populateListView() method with the code below:

```
private void populateListView() {
// Set adapter for ListView
ListView lvTest = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems); 

Cursor cursor = DBhelper.getAllItems(this);

// Manage cursor activity(when to close it if you don't know
// when)[DEBRECATED - Use Cursor Loader instead]
startManagingCursor(cursor);

// Setup Mapping from cursor to view fields
String[] fromFieldNames = { DBhelper.COLUMN_TN_ITEM};
int[] toViewIDs = { R.id.tvTouristItem };
// Create adapter to add DB data into elements of UI
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context
        R.layout.tn_listview_row, // Row Layout template
        cursor, // Cursor
        fromFieldNames, // DB Column names
        toViewIDs, // View IDs to put information
        0 // Flag
);
//Bind view to simpleCursorAdapter
cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        TextView tvItem = (TextView) view;

        String tnItem = cursor.getString(TN_ITEM_COLUMN);
        int itemIsSelected = cursor.getInt(TN_SELECTED_COLUMN);

        tvItem.setText(tnItem);

        if(itemIsSelected == 1){
           tvItem.setPaintFlags(tvItem.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }
else{
        tvItem.setPaintFlags( tvItem.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            }

        return true;
    }
});
lvTest.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```